# Unable to add objects and list together into a list of objects

Tags: java, rest, object, arraylist, jaxb

I am having a class in which I am trying to add an object of class Bookstore and a list of Books into a list of object. But, I am getting a typecast error while adding a list of books.

Here is my REST client:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

    ResponseList responseList = service.path("rest").path("BookMain/get").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(ResponseList.class);
    BookStore bs = (BookStore) responseList.getList().get(0);
    ArrayList<Book> lb = (ArrayList<Book>) responseList.getList().get(1);
}
```

Here is my class which is adding Bookstore object and list of books:

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public ResponseList addObjects() {

    BookStore bookstore = new BookStore();
    bookstore.setName("Prateek Bookstore");
    bookstore.setLocation("Vasanth Nagar");

    Book book1 = new Book();
    book1.setName("Book2");
    book1.setAuthor("Author2"); 

    Book book2 = new Book();
    book2.setName("Book3");
    book2.setAuthor("Author3");

    ArrayList<Book> Blist = new ArrayList<Book>();
    Blist.add(book1);
    Blist.add(book2);

    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(bookstore);
    list.addAll(Blist);

    ResponseList books = new ResponseList();
    books.setList(list);

    return books;
}
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:Book cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

This is my ResponseList:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({BookStore.class,Book.class,Hello.class})
public class ResponseList {

    private List<Object> list;

    public List<Object> getList() {
      return list;
    }
    public void setList(List<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

This is BookStore class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder = {"name", "location"})
public class BookStore {

    private String name;
    private String location;

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
      return location;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
      this.location = location;
    }
}
```

And this is the Book class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private String author;

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
      return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
      this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Cloud anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What is `ResponseList`? What do yo do to map a `List<Object>` to XML?

Comment: Now please add the classes from `@XmlSeeAlso`, too.

Comment: @Tichodroma Added, please have a look.

Comment: Do these JAXB classes work in a platin Java program? Do they serialize to the correct XML from `List<Object>`?

Comment: @Tichodroma Yes, I have tried only adding the Bookstore object. I got the correct output.

Comment: @Tichodroma But as soon as I am trying to add a list, it is giving me error

Comment: JAXB fails for me: `StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ResponseList.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.marshal(theList, writer);` throws an exception about `ArrayList` being unknown to JAXB.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33355/discussion-between-tichodroma-and-prats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at last line of your test class:

```
ArrayList<Book> lb = (ArrayList<Book>) responseList.getList().get(1);
```

If you evalulate

```
responseList.getList().get(1);
```

I think you will find this returns an instance of Book. You are trying to cast this to an ArrayList.

If you look at your addObjects method:

```
Book book1 = new Book();
book1.setName("Book2");
book1.setAuthor("Author2"); 

Book book2 = new Book();
book2.setName("Book3");
book2.setAuthor("Author3");

ArrayList<Book> Blist = new ArrayList<Book>();
Blist.add(book1);
Blist.add(book2);

ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(bookstore);
list.addAll(Blist);
```

You add all items of "Blist" to the ArrayList after adding the bookstore, so the second element of this ArrayList is a Book.

Try changing the last line of your test class to

```
Book book1 = (Book) responseList.getList().get(1);
Book book2 = (Book) responseList.getList().get(2);
```

Comment: No. `List.addAll(List l)` doesn't add `l` but each element of `l`.

Comment: If you had `list.add(Blist)` the second element would be an ArrayList, but you have `list.addAll(Blist)` which will add each book as an element.

Comment: @Carl Hembrough So are you telling me to change the Arraylist<Books> to only Books in my REST client ?

Comment: Either that or change the line `list.addAll(Blist);` in the addObjects method to `list.add(Blist);`

Comment: @CarlHembrough I used list.add(Blist) and then run my program then also the same results :(

Comment: Did you try and evaluate `responseList.getList().get(1);` in your client before you attempt the cast? what type is returned?

Comment: @CarlHembrough As, soon as I do responseList.getList().get(1) the server throws following exception : Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException:BookMain/get returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: OK. What I would suggest is you create a new class for the response that contains a BookStore and an ArrayList<Books>. Instead of populating the collection of objects have a more specifically typed class to hold the response contents.

Comment: I am already following that strategy, but I don't want to create a new class eachtime I add objects/ list of objects. I am trying to make it generic.

Comment: @CarlHembrough Do you have any other idea ?

Comment: I would suggest creating the classes for clarity. Alternatively reconsider the design. i.e, does the collection of books have to be seperate from the BookStore? can you change you BookStore object to contain the collection of books?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Collection<Object>` instead of `ArrayList<Object>` when dealing with rest.  You could always try to create a generic method such as:

EDIT:  nvm  Read Below.

You are putting a `Bookstore` object into the `arrayList` then a `book` object.  The objects must be the same when putting them into that `arrayList`.

EDIT2:  Change the 2nd to last line in the main to this:

```
ArrayList<BookStore> bsList = (BookStore) responseList.getList().get(0);
BookStore bs = bsList.get(0);
```

Comment: @Stephen D Could you please tell,how would I retrieve it from the REST client ?

Comment: @StephenD My arraylist is of object type, so I can any object in the list. It is not compulsary that I should put only book object or I should put only bookstore object.